# hive 2.3.9 can not start because: Couldn't create directory /tmp/hive/a44bc0d7-d01b-4c14-ae34-62a34d0b4827_resources

Tags: hive, hadoop3

> Hive 2.3.9
> Ubuntu16.04.3-64bit

I have started hadoop:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-all.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

and have create /tmp/hive folder in hdfs,and grant all permissions to /tmp:

```
$ cd $HADOOP_HOME/bin
$ ./hadoop fs -mkdir -p /tmp/hive
$ ./hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp

$ /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls /tmp
Found 2 items
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2021-06-29 17:58 /tmp/hadoop-yarn
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2021-07-06 16:03 /tmp/hive
```

but when I try to start hive,it fails:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:/home/hive/hive$ bin/hive
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't create directory /tmp/hive/7b9372f6-06d7-4c73-83ec-8c43db8e2c72_resources
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.util.ResourceDownloader.ensureDirectory(ResourceDownloader.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.util.ResourceDownloader.<init>(ResourceDownloader.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

in /etc/profile ,shall add below

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/hadoop/hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/hive/hive/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar
```